# Почему не получается вывести русские символы на в cmd через Python?

Tags: python, кодировка

Делаю так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy, os, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

print "++++++++++++++++++++++"
print u"03_Развитие_информационных_систем".decode("utf8")
print "++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

Пробовал так:

```
print "++++++++++++++++++++++"
print u"03_Развитие_информационных_систем"
print "++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

В итоге получаю на консоли:
`03_D D°D·D²D,Ñ,D,Dµ_D,D½Ñ,D_Ñ?D¼D°Ñ+D,D_D½D½Ñ<Ñ._Ñ?D,Ñ?Ñ,DµD¼`

Пробовал так же так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy, os, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('cp866')
print sys.getdefaultencoding()

print u"03_Развитие_информационных_систем".decode('UTF-8').encode('cp866')
```

Тоже не помогло.

Python 2.7 Windows 7 ENG

Comment: У вас utf-8 интерпретируется как близкое к iso-8859-1/cp1252. Как решить, см. ссылку выше.

Answer (score 1):

Просто

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"03_Развитие_информационных_систем".encode('cp866')
```

И не стоит трогать `sys.setdefaultencoding()`.