# Что означает знак процента в коде и как решить 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) ? - Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

```
msgid = '<%s.%s.%s%s@%s>' % (utcdate, pid, randint, idstring, domain)
```

В `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py` на строчке 67, на нее ругается джанго при попытке отправить письмо.

Из отладчика вижу значения параметров:

```
> utcdate
'20170902152117'
pid
6472
randint
39104
idstring
u''
domain
<django.core.mail.utils.CachedDnsName object at 0x027CCEB0>
```

Но вообще, т.к. я в джанго новичок, то мне непонятно `<%s.%s.%s%s@%s>` и может кто подскажет роль значка процента в этом выражении.

Ошибка выскакивает такая:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. "что означает знак процента в Питоне" и "UnicodeDecodeError"  отдельно следует спрашивать. Покажите полный traceback. Одной из причин ошибки может быть [смешивание байт и unicode без разбору](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540790/23044)  -- но не видя traceback сложно сказать и значений переменных сложно сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PS: Ошибка выскакивает такая: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Основная причина ошибки заключается в том, что кодировка по умолчанию, предполагаемая python - ASCII. Следовательно, если строковые данные, которые должны быть закодированы с помощью encode ('utf8'), содержат символ, который находится вне диапазона ASCII, например. для строки типа «hgvcj 터 파크 387», python будет вызывать ошибку, потому что строка не находится в ожидаемом формате кодирования.

Если вы используете версию python раньше версии 3.5, надежным решением было бы установить кодировку по умолчанию, принятую python, на utf8.

Добавьте эти строчки в начало кода:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Поставил, но теперь та же ошибка, но вместо ascii теперь utf8: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Сейчас прошелся в интерпретаторе все переменные попеременно исключая. Так вот если исключить idstring, то все работает: '<%s.%s.%s@%s>' % (utcdate, pid, randint, domain) прекрасно формирует строку <20170903074408.8540.37663@\xd1\xe0\xf8\xe0-\xcf\xca>. Если же добавить idstring - ошибка. idstring по прежнему равен u'', то есть пустая строка в юникоде. Если ее отдельно форматнуть, то тоже без ошибок '<%s>' % (idstring) дает u'<>'. Что за дела...

Comment: В общем опытным путем выяснено, что ошибку дает именно такое сочетание: '<%s@%s>' % (idstring, domain), то есть '<%s@%s>' % (u'', domain) или если без переменных '<%s@%s>' % (u'', '\xd1\xe0\xf8\xe0-\xcf\xca'). Странно

Comment: Кажется понял, дело в том, что '\xd1\xe0\xf8\xe0-\xcf\xca' без приставки u

Comment: -1: вредный вредный совет для начинающих (которые даже не знают, что такое `%s` в Питоне). Не следует использовать `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` как средство исправления ошибок, связанных с кодировкой.

Comment: Да, проблема вроде решена. Оказалась в том, что имя ПК в сети было в кириллице. Спасибо!

Comment: Потому что если повезёт, то ошибка останется (как в этом случае), а если не повезёт, то просто молча, не зная, данные испортите и получите [кракозябры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597183/23044). Необходимо искать первоначальную причину, а не пытаться симптомы скрыть — не зря вы вынуждены reload(sys) делать: как каждый хак, setdefaultencoding() может быть полезен людям, которые хорошо представляют последствия, но не нужно детям гранату давать.

Answer (score 1):

Данный код выполняет **форматирование строки**.

Форматирование строки позволяет выполнять подстановку в строку различных значений.
Для этого используется оператор %. Пример:

```
>>>name = 'Ivan'
>>>greeting = 'Hello, %s' % name
>>>greeting
'Hello, Ivan'
```

Слева от оператора % указывается строка, в которую будем подставлять значения, а справа - объект (либо кортеж, содержащий объекты), которые будут подставляться. Значения подставляются, замещая спецификатор %s.

В Вашем примере спецификаторов %s несколько. В этом случае справа указывается кортеж из элементов, которые необходимо подставить.
Пример:

```
>>>first_name = 'Ivan'
>>>second_name = 'Petrov'
>>>greeting = 'Hello, %s %s' % (first_name, second_name)
>>>greeting
'Hello, Ivan Petrov'
```

Спецификтор %s пожалуй самый распространенный. Он говорит, что на его место будет подставлена строка. Существуют и другие спецификаторы, например %d, который служит для подстановки целых чисел.